# Change root directory based on request url

Tags: php, nginx

We have a website where we are using a Laravel for the part available to the end-user, and an older legacy codebase for the admin panel.

Currently root is the `public` folder for the currently deployed version.

The website folder structure looks something like this:

```
admin/
  |____index.php <-- desired entrypoint for admin-related requests
app/

public/
  |____index.php <-- main entrypoint for website

resources/

routes/
```

So, when someone wants to access the admin panel they go to `example.com/admin`

Here's the current nginx configs file we are using.

`example.com`

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    root /var/www/example.com/current/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location /admin {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }

    error_page 404 /index.php;
    
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    
    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

`example.com/admin`

```
server {
    listen 3000;
    server_name example.com;
    root /var/www/example.com/current/admin;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

I'm not very well versed in nginx server configuration and would love som assistance on this.

**EDIT 1**

Config file using `map`:

**EDIT 2**

Updated the config below with the changes made to make it work.

```
map $uri $siteroot {
    # This didn't work, per the accepted answer.
    # ^/admin  /var/www/example.com/current/admin;

    # This works great!
    ^/admin   /var/www/example.com/current;
    default   /var/www/example.com/current/public;
}

server {
    server_name example.com;
    root $siteroot;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try changing root directory, Nginx will shows not found error.

Because, Nginx tries find file with request path even you changed root.

For example, If you change root directory for `/admin` path to `/app/admin`, Nginx will find file in `/app/admin/admin`. That's why you can't reach file.

Try insert `rewrite /admin(.*) $1 break;` line at `/admin` location block and set root path, or use [alias](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) expression.

Comment: This explains so much. I was thinking that it would be an issue with the path, but I didn't have a good way to troubleshoot where nginx was looking for the files. I'll try this out and get back to you.

Comment: Your explanation was very clear and allowed me to come up with a solution that fit my needs. I'll accept this as the answer now and award you the 50 points when I can (22 hours from now).

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) directive for this, something like

```
map $uri $siteroot {
    ~^/admin  /var/www/example.com/current/admin;
    default   /var/www/example.com/current/public;
}

server {
    server_name example.com;
    root $siteroot;
    ...
}
```

Comment: This does indeed look like what I was looking for. I'll try this tomorrow and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seems to work as intended. When I try to access `example.com/admin` I get `502 Bad Gateway`. If I try to access a specific file in the admin directory(`example.com/admin/index.php` for example) then I get `File not found`.
I've updated my question with the new config file(Also added the letsencrypt part of the config, even though I do not think it is relevant).